# Django import from a different model in another folder

Tags: django, pydev

I have two folders - modules and test - within my admin app. Each folder contains its own models. I'm trying to import between the two folders.

Importing from modules in test: `from exam.admin.modules.models import Subject`

It works fine, but Pydev Eclipse shows me an unresolved import error. Any reason?

Comment: As long as it works when you run it, you can ignore what Eclipse thinks.

Comment: Am I doing the right thing? Is that the practice?

Comment: There is probably a way to make Eclipse behave; however, in my experience it is never worth the time and effort. The only exception is if things don't work when you run them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have said, as long as your program runs then you can safely ignore PyDev/Eclipse's warning. PyDev seems to like relative imports within a project. You could leave off the project name from the import path, but there's a clearer way to show the hierarchy using dots. "Go up one level, into the modules directory, and import Subject from the models.py file."

`from ..modules.models import Subject`

More on Python importing standards (absolute versus relative recommendations) in [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to configure Source Folders and check if this can solve the problem.
Right click on the Project, click on Properties.
Open the PyDev - PYTHONPATH tab.
Check the Source Folders defined.
These Source Folders are your "root" source folders. 
Probably there is no source folder for the directory of the not found classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about PyDev's import error if your app works. [I am sure there are bugs in PyDev/Eclipse](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=browse&group_id=85796&atid=577329&status=1)